# Combine two selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with two sql querys.
The one sql selects some ID's and the other one sets the id structur.
The problem is I can't get them both to work as one query.

The SQL which sets the structure:

```
select nstrid 
from t_ousernstr 
where kstrid = 116 And 
Bis is null
Order by nstrid
```

The id's from that are like:

```
100
200
300
400
```

And the SQL which gets the user id's:

```
SELECT
    T_OUSER.ID                                      AS ID,
    FROM
    T_OUSER,
    T_OUSERNSTR
    WHERE 
            ( T_OUSERNSTR.NSTRID = ANY(//here should be the id's from above))
            (T_OUSERNSTR.VON is null or SYSDATE >=T_OUSERNSTR.VON) and
            (T_OUSERNSTR.BIS is null) and
            (T_OUSERNSTR.BEGINN IS NULL OR T_OUSERNSTR.BEGINN<= SYSDATE) and
            (T_OUSERNSTR.ENDE is null or T_OUSERNSTR.ENDE> SYSDATE)                                 
    Order By T_OUSER.ID;
```

Comment: How are these two queries supposed to be related?

Comment: Simply `... where T_OUSERNSTR.NSTRID IN (select nstrid 
from t_ousernstr 
where kstrid = 116 And 
Bis is null) ...`?

Comment: Are you sure your 2nd query is correct? There is no correlation between the 2 tables used. I'm pretty sure you deleted the join condition in the line `T_OUSERNSTR.NSTRID = ANY(//here should be the id's from above)`. Also you use the same table in both queries couldn't you simple do `T_OUSERNSTR.KSTRID = 116` (if `NSTRID`is the primary key as i suppose)?

Comment: @Radagast81 If `NSTRID` is not the primary key then you can't do a filter like that as there could be one row that matches the other (date) filter conditions and a second row that matches the `KSTRID` condition for a `NSTRID`/`BIS` window.

Comment: @MT0 Yeah that's why I stated it that way and formulized it as question and not as statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```sql
SELECT o.ID AS ID
FROM   T_OUSER o
       CROSS JOIN
       T_OUSERNSTR n
WHERE  n.NSTRID IN ( select nstrid 
                     from   t_ousernstr 
                     where  kstrid = 116
                     And    Bis is null )
AND    ( n.BIS    IS NULL )
AND    ( n.VON    IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.VON    )
AND    ( n.BEGINN IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.BEGINN )
AND    ( n.ENDE   IS NULL OR SYSDATE <  n.ENDE   )                                 
ORDER BY o.ID;
```

or `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT o.ID AS ID
FROM   T_OUSER o
       CROSS JOIN
       T_OUSERNSTR n
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   t_ousernstr x
         WHERE  x.kstrid = 116
         AND    x.Bis    IS NULL
         AND    ( n.NSTRID = x.NSTRID OR ( n.NSTRID IS NULL AND x.NSTRID IS NULL ) )
       )
AND    ( n.BIS    IS NULL )
AND    ( n.VON    IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.VON    )
AND    ( n.BEGINN IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.BEGINN )
AND    ( n.ENDE   IS NULL OR SYSDATE <  n.ENDE   )                                 
ORDER BY o.ID;
```

or to remove the correlated sub-query you could use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT o.ID AS ID
FROM   T_OUSER o
       CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT n.*,
                MAX( CASE WHEN kstrid = 116 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY bis, nstrid )
                  AS has_kstrid
         FROM   T_OUSERNSTR n
       ) n
WHERE  n.has_kstrid = 1
AND    ( n.BIS    IS NULL )
AND    ( n.VON    IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.VON    )
AND    ( n.BEGINN IS NULL OR SYSDATE >= n.BEGINN )
AND    ( n.ENDE   IS NULL OR SYSDATE <  n.ENDE   )                                 
ORDER BY o.ID;
```

Comment: `IN` and null values is no problem. It's `NOT IN` with null values that surprise people.

Comment: @jarlh Updated to remove that small part and make it more generic.